# redirected you too many times after installing smush and jetpack plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

redirected you too many times

Hello I am having (redirected you too many times) problem. please do you have the solution for my problem. on my website jetpack plugin was intalled and the i installed smush plugin. after that i am having redirected you too many times error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache and resetting your .htaccess file.

You could also try updating the permalinks.

Here's a useful article on this:

https://blog.hubspot.com/website/too-many-redirects